# ExtJS & FontAwesome: Screen reader compatibility

Tags: extjs, font-awesome

I have an application which has to be screen readable (for blind people) and I'm struggling to read a FontAwesome Icon. Right now I have this for example:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [
    {
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-envelope',
    }],
    dataIndex: 'edit',
    text: 'Send E-Mail'
}
```

And I use NVDA Screen reader -> https://www.nvaccess.org/download/

However it cannot read this text ("Send E-Mail") on mouse hover. I know that font-awesome has option to include `aria-label="Send E-Mail"` but how can I apply it to ExtJS item?

Comment: I'm currently working this issue as well. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @harryBundles Not yet. Apparently fonts are not screen readable for now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
{
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-envelope',
    tooltip: 'Send E-Mail',
}
```

Comment: It works but only when I hover the tooltip. I want screen reader to work when I hover the icon.

Comment: What version of Extjs you are using?

Comment: ExtJS 6. The latest one.

Comment: Try use that property in the button:  ariaLabel: 'Send E-mail'

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to make the "actioncolumn" compliant, so I have converted them to a "widgetcolumn" and that works better. The downsides to this is that you cannot have multiple "widgets" in one column, so each of actions will get its own column and you have buttons in the columns instead of the more elegant icons. But, what can you do, Ext....

```
{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    text: 'Edit', //column header
    align: 'center',
    width: 60,
    widget: {
        xtype: 'button',
        width: 40,
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-pencil',
        ariaLabel: 'click to edit',
        handler: 'edit'
    }
}
```

For the handler, the arguments are a little different since it's now a button (this is specific to my case, using the record id):

```
edit: function(button) {
    var grid = button.up('grid'),
        store = grid.getStore(),
        recordId = button.getWidgetRecord().getId(),
        record = store.findRecord('id', recordId);
    //and so on....
}
```